# How to access the local hyperledger fabric

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm not a blockchain/VS Code/Docker expert - followed the [Develop a smart contract with the IBM Blockchain Platform VS Code extension tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/ibm-blockchain-platform-vscode-smart-contract/) and could create and update the asset successfully. Later I continued [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain/howto?topic=blockchain-develop-vscode#develop-vscode-submitting-transactions).

[image]

The Hyperledger fabric was installed via the Hyperledger Composer Extension for VSCode and is running on Docker on my Mac.

```
$ docker images
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                                           1.4.1               3a1799cda5d7        3 months ago        252MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                                                                                        1.4.1               432c24764fbb        3 months ago        1.55GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                                                                                        1.4.1               d7433c4b2a1c        3 months ago        1.43GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                                                      1.4.1               ec4ca236d3d4        3 months ago        173MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                                         1.4.1               a1e3874f338b        3 months ago        178MB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                                                      0.4.15              8de128a55539        3 months ago        1.5GB
hyperledger/fabric-baseimage                                                                                                    0.4.15              c4c532c23a50        3 months ago        1.39GB
```

Instead of using a SDK I want to directly access the local fabric through REST from Node-RED, can I use the [Hyperledger Composer REST server](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server) to do this? What would be the necessary steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There is no longer any active development for Hyperledger Composer as much of the Composer functionality is being shifted to core Fabric and the SDKs (via the new programming model).

If you want to use REST, you'll need to build your own REST server which uses the SDK on the back end.

You should be able to build a custom node for Node-RED which uses the Node SDK though.